# Drawable setState returns true but does not change appearance

Tags: android, android-view, drawable, android-framelayout

I am using ForegroundLinearLayout (https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/library-core/src/main/java/it/gmariotti/cardslib/library/view/ForegroundLinearLayout.java).
It is a pretty simple implementation.

However, I have put put some ForegroundLinearLayouts in RecyclerViews, and sometimes (about 50% of the time) the pressed state of my foreground will not appear until the View has been recycled (I scroll down past the first screen of Views).

I think the problem lies in mForegroundDrawable.setState(getDrawableState()).

I discovered that drawableStateChanged() is being called in my ForegroundLinearLayouts, and getDrawableState() is showing the correct values when I press and release the View, and mForegroundDrawable.setState(getDrawableState()) is even returning true.

Even explicitly calling mForegroundDrawable.invalidateSelf() and this.invalidate() in the ForegroundLinearLayout did not help, though.

The pressed state will not appear about 50% of the time on the first screen of views.  Using the view's background works, but the foreground does not.

Anybody have any ideas what's broken?

I really don't want to have to wrap all my ForegroundLinearLayouts in FrameLayouts.

Answer (score 1):

This comes way too late, but I stumbled upon your comment in the original [gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/9091754)

Setting the bounds on every `draw()` is unnecessary.

As corsair992 already pointed out `draw()` already sets the bounds properly in most cases. However, if `onLayout()` gets called multiple times before `draw()` the flag `mForegroundBoundsChanged` for setting the bounds gets set to `false` and the bounds never get set.
I ran into this issue with a DrawerLayout and left a comment in the original gist, but here is a simple fix:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (changed) mForegroundBoundsChanged = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me 3 days to figure this one out.

My foreground bounds (mForeground.getBounds()) was returning a 0, 0 -- 0, 0 Rect sometimes.  When it did work, it would return the correct bounds 0, 0 -- width, height.

If anybody knows why, please tell me because I am going to do a pull request on ForegroundLinearLayout.

I simply put this line in in draw(Canvas canvas) after the null check on mForeground:
mForeground.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

Boom, fixed everything.

But, should the foreground always have those bounds?  I don't think so; I think I need to account for padding and such.  I'll look more into it, but any comment here would be invaluable.

Comment: The bounds already seem to be set properly in the `draw()` method according to the defined foreground gravity (full by default), if the layout has been changed or initialized. On the other hand, the bounds don't seem to be set properly if the foreground drawable is set after the view has been layout and drawn, so that seems to be the only case where the bounds might not have been initialized properly.